# Failing to render squishit bundal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, squishit

If I have a partial view, named: _jquery.cshtml, view like so:

```
@(Bundle.JavaScript()
.Add("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js")
.Add("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")
)
```

and render the partial view, using:

```
<head>
...
@Html.Partial("_jquery", theme)
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

all I get rendered is:

```
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
SquishIt.Framework.JavaScript.JavaScriptBundle
```

I am doing something wrong obviously. This is inside an IFrame, within the main Layout. I would be grateful if someone is able to point out my problem. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always when learning a new, not so new anymore, thing, it takes some time. I missed the line:

```
.MvcRender("~/.../filename.js")
```

It is now rendering as it should. so the partial view now looks like this:

```
@(Bundle.JavaScript()
   .Add("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js")
   .Add("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")
   .MvcRender("~/.../filename.js")
)
```

I hope others can learn from my mistake.